# What can one do with a captured spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, treasure

My players captured two spellbooks. [What is the monetary worth of a captured spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/126041/11402)

The other question addresses the market value of a captured spellbook.

Now, assuming the books were captured moments ago, what can be done with them?

These options below are moot **and do not need to be addressed on the answers**:

- Let the party wizard copy spells onto his own spellbook.
- Use it as a campfire fuel.
- Allow the halfling to reach the top shelf, make as a decorative item, etc.
- Attempt to convince Candlekeep wardens to accept the books as a gift and grant you entry.

Besides the ones listed above, what else can be done with a captured spellbook?

Comment: This feels a bit idea-generation and too broad.

Comment: @Mindwin Do you mean by RAW only?

Comment: @nautarch that is why therre is a RAW tag. So people doesnt go overboard and stick to the canon

Comment: @bloodcinder so people does not brainstorm some other homebrew uses for it.

Comment: No, I know what the tag means. I didn't notice the tag was there, because people were closing the question as if it was opinion-based. But it's not opinion-based. By RAW, there are only so many ways a spellbook can be used. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @bloodcinder yeah, but at this moment it is not a bit change. A raw answer was already posted and accepted. Thanks for noticing the tag anyway. P.S.: and only after posting this I noticed that you were the answererer!!!! XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Effectively, that's it.

A wizard's spellbook serves one utility: to allow the wizard that who wrote the spellbook to prepare spells from it. This is the only inherent utility granted by the rules.

Additionally, another wizard (or multiple wizards) can copy spells from it. A generous DM *might* allow another wizard to study it thoroughly to decipher it to the extent that it effectively becomes their own spellbook (this is implied by [my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/126045/32426) to your companion question on cost and is elaborated upon in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65369/32426) on using another wizard's spellbook).

Otherwise, there is no utility the spellbook serves besides anything a mundane object made of paper can do. Anything else is homebrew territory for the DM.